# Need Help Solving Sparse Ax=b

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, linear-algebra

I know there is a lot of information out there on this topic, but I'm struggling to find the best solution for my specific problem.

For my problem, A is extremely large (~145k X 145k) and extremely sparse (max of 9 non-zero values per row). It is not positive definite, nor symmetric, and is complex valued (single precision). The sparsity pattern can be visualized by imagining a tridiagonal matrix, and then adding two "tridiagonals" above and below that, N away from the main tridiagonal. This gives 3 sets of 3 non zeros in each row, with sets of 3 separated by N (N is constant for a given matrix A), and centered on the main diagonal. ~5% of rows will not fill all 9 non-zero positions, due to boundary conditions, so these rows will have a subset of the main non-zero pattern.

I need to solve for multiple right hand sides (~1024). I also need to resolve the same system with different numeric values in A, but the same sparsity pattern.  Currently, I'm using SuperLU (single threaded) to factor A to LU and then solving using cusparse (specifically, cusparseCcsrsm_solve).

Is a sparse direct solver using LU factorization the best approach for my problem? Which library would be the fastest for LU factorization? Which would be the fastest for solving with back substitution?

Comment: Try condensing the question down further; it's unclear what it is that you're actually asking.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of being the fastest in direct solvers I am more leaning towards `MUMPS`. 
The libraries that are the main players and are actively developed (at least the ones I know and have used) are `MUMPS`, `SuperLU`, `UMFPACK`, `SuiteSparse`, `Trilinos` and `PETSc`.

If I were to do this I would use a robust iterative solver and precondition it with incomplete LU factorisation.

There is a very well known rule of thumb between users of iterative solvers, if your system is larger than 4x4 then you need to use an iterative solver.

If you want to use iterative solvers, I would suggest to use `Trilinos` or `PETSc`. The main difference is that the former is object oriented while the later is not. There isn't much of performance difference between them.

For GPU programming I don't have enough experience. I once used a library called PARALUTION which is a nice library. It hides the GPU implementation for you.

Comment: Could I ask why you would use an iterative solver? Could it really compete in terms of speed given that I have ~1024 right hand sides? I'm leaning towards checking out Trilinos, as it provides a common interface to a few different iterative and direct solvers. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Well, the iterations of iterative solvers are cheap (O(N)) while it is higher for direct solvers. With a good preconditioner an iterative solver beats a direct solver. If the system matrix is well conditioned then chances are that you get the exact (or something very close to exact) LU from Incomplete LU and then an iterative solver will converge in as few as two iterations.